# Item that must be processed by only one service

Tags: architecture, cqrs

How would you solve the following problem in a CQRS architecture:

1. There is a domain entity called Order.
2. An Order needs to be processed.
3. Newly created Orders are unprocessed and in a processing queue
4. Each Order must not be processed multiple times.
5. There are multiple windows services that query (read side of things) for unprocessed Orders.

Now, how do I ensure that each Order is processed by only one service?

I would make the service issue a Command `StartOrderProcessing(order)`. This command will fail in the Domain if another service already startet processing this order as the versions differ.
However, as the Command is asynchronous in nature, how does the service know about the failure?

Should the service poll the read model to see if the order changed its status to processing? But how would the service now that it changed the status because of its own command and not because of the command of another service?

---

UL:

- Order: An Order in my system represents a user request to update the Greeting on his/her Mailbox.
- Mailbox: When you call a cell phone and the call is not picked up, you are redirected to the mailbox to leave a message
- Greeting: When you arrive at the mailbox you are greeted with a text telling you to leave your message after the beep. This text (not your message!) is the Greeting.
- Activation: The process of setting a new Greeting in a Mailbox is called Activation. A Greeting is being activated.
- Carrier: The company that provides the cell phone services, e.g. T-Mobile.

Steps when processing an Order:

1. Create the Greeting from pre-recorded sound bits. This varies depending on the Carrier the Mailbox is associated with.
2. Execute a Carrier specific workflow to activate the Greeting on the Mailbox. This workflow has these elements:

   2.1. Call the Mailbox
   2.2. Navigate the mailbox menu using DTMF tones
   2.3. Recognizing certain audio elements the Mailbox sends (like a confirmation beep)
   2.4. Play the Greeting that was created in 1

   The workflow is defined as a Windows Workflow Foundation workflow as it is different for each Carrier.
3. On success:

   3.1. Save recording of the activation call
   3.2. Notify user via mail about success
4. On error:

   4.1. Save recording of the failed activation call and reason of failure
   4.2. If this was the first try, schedule Order for retry in X minutes
   4.3. If this was the second try, notify user via mail about failure

Comment: Must the service wait for the processing to complete? Why? Could the service, or any service, instead listen to the event that occurs when processing is done?

Comment: @MikaelÖstberg: The service is *doing* the processing. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

First you need to sort out your dequeuing so that only one service instance can dequeue and process the Order. Check this out: http://www.eaipatterns.com/CompetingConsumers.html

NServiceBus for instance gives you that out of the box.

Then you probably want to think about your order processing. **StartOrderProcessing** doesn't sound like a business step to me. What are the real steps to handle an Order?

The processing of an order might actually be a finite state machine. It has an entry point and one or more exit conditions.

Have a look at the saga concept, where an aggregate can go trough a state machine and gather information which it can send to the domain or other bounded contexts in order to let them make decisions which in turn will push the saga forward.

Have a look at this: https://github.com/haf/Documently/wiki/Sagas-SnowPloughExample

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I updated my question with the specific steps of processing an order. Maybe you can refine your answer a little bit as I am honestly not sure I can correctly transfer it to my use case.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like there's not just an `Order` but a distinction between `UnprocessedOrder` and `ProcessedOrder`. Maybe these should be modelled separately to reflect the domain. This would not only refine the domain model but also can help simplify your very issue.

Comment: Maybe you are right. But this would introduce more classes: `ErroneousOrder` and `OrderScheduledForRetry`. And how would this help with my issue?